# Auto increment django model field per user

Tags: django, django-models, model, field, auto-increment

I have this model:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    owner  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    data   = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False)
```

What I need is to auto-increment the field `number` for each separated user. The rationale is that each user has a list of `Invoice`, starting from `number=1` to `number=latest.number+1`.

I do known about `F()` expressions, but can't figure out how to reference the latest/greatest `number` for each specific user. Maybe `Invoice.objects.filter(owner=request.user).aggregate(Max('number'))` is the path, but how do I ensure there is no race conditions between `Max()` and  `F()`?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Alasdair Postgres 9.4

Comment: @MTaqi an auto increment field will increment regardless of which user the Invoice belongs to. I need to be able to have Invoice.number=1 for all users. Thinks of your own telco invoice numbering: it starts from 1 and increments until you call to cancel the service, for each client.

Comment: It'd be nice to have something like `models.PositiveIntegerField(auto_increment_for('owner'))`

Comment: Why not have a date field, which will tell you the latest invoice as well for each user.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Because I need invoices to be numbered as a sequence. That seams to be the most natural way.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this and similar functions by overriding save method in model and writing your custom logics to it.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    owner  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    data   = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk:
            self.number += 1
        # Write all your logic here, like handeling max value etc
        return super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Ok, but that won't prevent a race condition, when 2 concurrent clients try to save at (almost) the same time. That is why I believe it must be done using F() expression. That way the increment operation is done at the database level.

Comment: you can handle IntegrityError and wait for random time to avoid race condition. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3523439/1240938

Comment: May be F() is better option. I haven't used it ever.

Comment: Here is the best solution to your problem: check latest saved invoice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28199417/1240938

Comment: This is not a solution for multithreading applications, neither are any of both options in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your first or last object like this:

```
# For last Object
Model.objects.latest('field') # Field can be id or pk or ...

# For first Object
Model.objects.all().first() # You can also use it on filter
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is you can make the *number* field as the primary key since its nature would be similar.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    owner  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    data   = models.TextField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    number = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

Or, you can make *number* as AutoField or BigAutoField.

```
number = models.AutoField()
```