# Django model field automatically incremented, but not according IDs

Tags: django, model, autocomplete, field

I am a beginner with Django and I have been searching around this but not reaching a satisfactory solution.

Let's say I would like to create a Model to identify a given **chair** of a **table** located in a given **room** of a **house**, and also its **height** (of the chair). Consider then records like the following:

| House | Room | Table | Chair | Chair Height (cm) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| White House | Kitchen | 1 | 1 | 75 |
| White House | Kitchen | 2 | 1 | 55 |
| White House | Kitchen | 2 | 2 | 65 |
| Buckingham Palace | Main State Room | 1 | 1 | 70 |
| Buckingham Palace | Main State Room | 1 | 2 | 70 |

The compound primary key should include House, Room, Table and Chair. The model I have created does not allow me to increment the integer value of the Chair, once the House, Room and Table are introduced. Is there a way to do that **in the models.py** file? I do not want to allow the user to introduce any number for the **chair** field, but to introduce the corresponding following one according to the house, room and table already introduced (There should not be, for example, a 3rd chair without existing the 1st and the 2nd ones).

I have been searching the AutoField type but it does not seem to be what I want. Has this to be considered in other parts of the development? (User forms...)

Thank you very much in advance.

```
class ChairLocation(models.Model):
    house = models.CharField()
    room = models.CharField()
    table = IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    chair = IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])   #¿?¿?¿?¿?

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('house', 'room', 'table', 'chair),)
```

...

Comment: Take a look at that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922447/auto-increment-django-model-field-per-user

Comment: Thank you for your help @BriseBalloches but I do not reach the solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the save method of you model, then get the highest value of chair and increment it yourself.

```py
from django.db.models import Max

class ChairLocation(models.Model):
    house = models.CharField()
    room = models.CharField()
    table = IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    chair = IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])   #¿?¿?¿?¿?

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('house', 'room', 'table', 'chair'),)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        max_chair = 0
        try:
            max_chair = ChairLocation.objects.filter(house=self.house, room=self.room, table=self.table).aggregate(Max('chair'))["chair__max"]
        except:
            max_chair = 0
        self.chair = max_chair + 1
        return super(ChairLocation, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It seems it is doing something but I do not know exactly what. It is including always the value "2" for the field, like if it was always getting into the except:

Comment: WAIT! It was my fault since I did not imported the Max!  It is working now!

Comment: How is it posible to "say thanks" here in stackoverflow? isn't it a "thankyou" button?

Comment: Validating the answer and upvoting is the way ! No problem ! :)

Comment: My reputation is under 15... I can validate but not upvote :( Thank you very much!